# Why can't Spring find a default constructor when it is right there?

Tags: java, spring, enums, javabeans

I keep getting the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'category' defined in file [/home/dazikiri_anikar/IdeaProjects/shop/target/classes/pl/shop/models/Category.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pl.shop.models.Category]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pl.shop.models.Category.<init>()
```

Here is the class that Spring has a problem with:

```
package pl.shop.models;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Component
public enum Category {

    HEALTHY_FOOD,
    JUNK_FOOD,
    TEAS_AND_COFFEES,
    SPICES,
    GRAINS_AND_LENTILS,
    NUTS_AND_SEEDS,
    DRIED_FRUITS,
    SNACKS,
    DRINKS;

    private String categoryName;
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

All the answers I am finding are... to define a default constructor. Which... is right there,
the @NoArgsConstructor from Lombok, right?
And even if I remove this and define it myself, it doesn't change a thing.

I tried defining both constructors (no args and all args) myself to no avail and then added
@Autowired which resulted in an error that there is not 'String' bean which makes me absolutely clueless at this stage.

Please, help.

Comment: Why is your enum annotated as a @Component? Spring can't construct an instance of your enum to use as a component because it's an enum: It can only have those instances that are listed in its definition. That is what being an enum means.

Comment: did you installed lombook in your ide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, Enum only has private constructors. Hence can’t be instantiated by Spring

Comment: So does it mean I can basically say bye-bye to my Enum and I need another solution? Anyway, many thanks. :)

Comment: You can use enums just no need for spring to instantiate them. In your case you want to match enum against a list of products. You probably should create a Map in some other class (which can be instantiated then by Spring if so needed) and in the map use enum values as keys and list of product as values.